# Cloning from Src delta table VS overwriting from Src delta table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I've delta tables, say `prod_table`(source of truth) and `dev_table`(meant to break). During development, schema of `dev_table` have gone bad due to multiple Developers working and now I want to update it according to our approved schema so I decided to take a copy from my `prod_table` and dump it into `dev_table`. To do so, I've two options and I'm wondering if there is any pros/cons of using one over the other.

##### Method 1 (standard procedure)

From [Databricks documentation][1],

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dev_table
   DEEP CLONE prod_table LOCATION 'abfss://<table-path>'
```

##### Method 2 (bit of a hack)

```py
df_prod = DeltaTable.forName(spark, 'prod_table').toDF()
(df_prod.write.format('delta')
.mode('overwrite')
.option('overwriteSchema', 'true')
.option('path', 'abfss://<table-path>')
.saveAsTable('dev_table'))
```

I understand that Method-1 is short and crisp but I'm just wondering if Method-2 has any downfalls.

[1] https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html

Answer (score 1):

Really it should behave the same way, the only thing that I can simplify is to replace

```
df_prod = DeltaTable.forName(spark, 'prod_table').toDF()
(df_prod.write.format('delta')
...
```

with

```
spark.read.table('prod_table').write.format('delta')...
```

to make code more clear